# How to document AWS Lambda with Swagger?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, swagger, openapi

I am a Junior Java Developer and was asked to implement OpenAPI (Swagger) documentation on the AWS Lambdas we have here. I've been searching online for some material about this but didn't find anything really substantial.

Any kind of guidance would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

You don't document Lambda functions with Swagger, you document an API. That API  may be backed by AWS Lambda functions, but that technical detail is really irrelevant to the API documentation. You should be looking at how to document your AWS API Gateway, not your Lambda functions.

Also, Swagger is the old name for what is now called OpenAPI.

AWS API Gateway supports exporting OpenAPI documentation for both [REST](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-import-api.html) and [HTTP](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/http-api-open-api.html) APIs.

Comment: Thank you! It really makes sense. Now I have a "north".

Comment: Do you recommend anything to document AWS API Gateway?

Comment: Yes, I recommend using the OpenAPI export that I linked in my answer, to document API Gateway. That's basically the entire content of the answer I gave, so I'm unclear why you are asking that now.